# IK refusing to follow target around Z axis

Tags: rigging, bones

The IK have set up does not follow the target around the Z axis. I am using an Empty as the IK target. You can download the blend [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33097).

[image: OpenGL render of issue]

[image: Scene view]

[image: Outliner] [image: IK settings]

Each bone except the bottom one has the following IK constraints;

[image: IK constraints]

And the bottom bone;

[image: IK constraints]

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do it properly:

The IK limits should be used only when needed. The limits on last 3 (Proximal, Middle and Distal) bones are fine.

Now change the IK constraint chain length to 3, this will remove the first bone from IK chain.

[image: IK constraint settings]

Instead rotate the bone with constraint, here is a LockedTrack that will also constrain the Y axis so the fingers end can move up and down with the base in correct orientation. This will also solve any flipping issue.

[image: Locked Track constraint]

If you need to position the finger in space, do it with parenting it to a bone and then transforming that bone. Everything will keep working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I deactivated the x-axis limits for the three end bones and the odd error clears up as shown below.

[image]

[image]

I re-enabled the limits but changed the range from -90 to 90 for all 3 bones and tested it with some fairly exaggerated movements of the curve and the animation seems to behave sensibly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The issue with this method is that the bones still snap to 180 degrees. If you look at the bone axes themselves, they are flipped when 180 degrees is reached. This can especially be seen in a non symmetrical model, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oD4NV.gif).

Answer (score 3):

If the default **Standard** IK solver is not satisfactory, you may want to try the **iTaSC** solver.

[image]

[image]

Comparing to Standard solver:

- iTaSC is a generic multi-constraint IK solver.
- iTaSC has a stateful mode, which means that the pose at frame n+1 is computed from the pose at frame n. (Simulation mode).
- It also supports a stateless mode, identical to iksolver operation mode, where the pose is computed from the rest pose (or animation pose) at each frame by reiterations until the constraints are met. (*Animation* mode)

[WIKI documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/GameEngine/RobotIKSolver)

Answer (score 0):

Jack, this is a problem with 'zero-lock' in the IK of the bottom bone, as your assymetrical final example shows clearly.  I suggest keeping the limits on and set to -90 to 90 for the top 3 bones (as in the first answer), but further you should change the bottom bone limits so they range from 0 to 359. This should put the flicker artifact directly pointed at the camera as the motion passes in front of the model -- it still will happen, you just won't 'see' it as bad.

Please post a result to show pass/fail.

Comment: sorry but rig that works only from certain camera angle is a bad rig.

Comment: The issue with gimble (zero) lock is pervasive in most software and needs to be worked around. The bottom bone in your model will rotate all the way around, it just needs to reset the measure of the angle. My answer simply points out that the best place to reset the measure of an angle is when pointed at the camera/user. It's not a faulty model nor a software bug, just an implementation consideration.